# How can I make a .svg file to fill a 100% width of its <div> container?

Tags: html, css, svg

Hi,

I'm trying to insert a .SVG into a div container. My problem is that I can't make the svg file to stretch itself to a 100% width. My code is the following:

```
<html> 
   <div id="frame1">
     <img src="svg/layer1.svg">
   </div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#frame1{
      width:100%;
      height: 400px;
      background-color: transparent;
}
```

SVG file:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 x="0px" y="0px"width="800px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 800 400" 
enable-background="new 0 0 800 400" xml:space="preserve">
<g><defs><rect id="SVGID_1_" x="0" y="-0.371" width="800" height="400.742"/>
```

I tried with set `preserveAspectRatio="none"`, and setting width to 100% inside the svg parameters but it is not working so far.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove `width="800px" height="400px"` from the SVG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
width="800px" height="400px"
```

in your SVG to

```
width="100%" height="100%"
```

See here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/BVgr4/). `test1.svg` is your file and `test2.svg` is the file with the modifications above.

Comment: It works with both, removing width-height altogether or with both being percent parameters. Apparently it doesn't work with one parameter being percent and the other bien pixels. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You might also have to change the aspect ratio:

Change

```
width="800px" height="400px"
```

in your SVG to

```
width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio